# Can't find where my error is: Find $k(t)$ given $\mathbf r(t) = \langle3t^{-1}, 6, t\rangle$.

Tags: calculus, parametric, curvature

I began with the formula: $k(t) = \frac{||\mathbf r'(t) \times\mathbf r''(t)|| }{ ||\mathbf r'(t)||^3}$.

My $\mathbf r'(t) = \langle -3t^{-2}, 0, 1\rangle$ and $||\mathbf r'(t)|| = \sqrt{9t^{-4}+1}$.

Thus, $\mathbf r''(t) = \langle 6t^{-3}, 0, 0\rangle$.

Taking the cross product of $\mathbf r' $ and $\mathbf r'' $ was $\langle 0, 6t^{-3}, 0\rangle$. The length of this is $6/t^3$.

When I divide this by $||\mathbf r'(t)||^3$, my homework says the answer is incorrect. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

After the simplifications you have arrived at $k(t)=\frac{6/t^3}{(9/t^4+1)^{3/2}}$. We can multiply top and bottom by $t^6=(t^4)^{3/2}$ to remove the singularity at $t=0$:
$$k(t)=\frac{6t^3}{(9+t^4)^{3/2}}$$
Try and see if this works.

Comment: Whoops; I meant to put that originally. It still says that is incorrect. Any other ideas?

Comment: @warpspeed86 What are you putting into the software?

Comment: (6*[t^(-3)])/([sqrt(9*[t^(-4)]+1)]^3) is what I put in, and the answer preview looked correct. It still says it's incorrect though.

Comment: @warpspeed86 See edit.